# How can I register a collections directory without clobbering the Racket's default(s)?

Tags: racket

So, basically, I'm trying to register a local collections `collects/` directory containing modules that I don't want to be global (e.g. not in `/usr/share/racket/collects`) for the interpeter to use.

However, in doing this, I think I've ran into a problem where I can set the path using something like: `scheme_set_collects_path(scheme_make_path("/hardcoded/absolute/path/to/collects"));` but then it appears to clobber the system-wide racket collections (error is encountered where it tries to interpret the module header `#lang racket` - I think).

I can't give an exact rundown since I've since scrapped major contextual elements of this, so all I can really ask is: is it even possible to embed Racket such that you can interpret local source files?

I've looked at the header files and seen `scheme_init_collection_paths_post`, which allows you to specify *pre* and *post* paths for collections. However, I don't know if these paths completely clobber any defaults, or how do pass an empty path to *pre*.

Currently my idea is to register a local collections path in the same folder as my executable and *dynamically require* functions from local collections. So I must register a path without messing up the defaults (since doing short-form `#lang racket` requires "racket" collection).

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
((dynamic-require ''mypackage/mymodule 'myfunction))
```

where `'myfunction` is *provided* by `'mymodule`.

I've not quite wrapped my head around how you actually use the `scheme_`* functions, so I've done this:

```
Scheme_Object* a[2];
a[0] = scheme_intern_symbol("mypackage/mymodule");
a[1] = scheme_intern_symbol("myfunction");
Scheme_Object* func = scheme_dynamic_require(2, a);
scheme_apply(func, 0, NULL);
```

I don't believe that's actually how you'd go about dynamically requiring functions properly but I vaguely copied it from the dynamic require Racket REPL example.

The error I'm getting now is:

```
standard-module-name-resolver: collection not found
  for module path: mypackage/mymodule
  collection: "mypackage"
  in collection directories:
  context...:
   show-collection-err
   standard-module-name-resolver
SIGSEGV MAPERR si_code 1 fault on addr 0xd8
[1]    7102 abort (core dumped)  ./main
```

Ignore the fact I've called the collection "mypackage". This error is the most recent error. Previously, it could resolve the local collections (I've basically been doing `raco pkg install --link mypackage` and then copying that into a local `collects/` folder - since I know installing packages compiles them) but it wouldn't be able to load any "racket" modules (such as the one required by `#lang racket`).

So, how do you register an *extra* - local - collections directory for Racket's interpreter?

Comment: After reading your question, I’m unclear *why* exactly you want to do this rather than simply use the package system. Why is it important your code is part of `collects/`?

Comment: Well, initially my intention was to simply interpret racket files (`.rkt`). However, there's no examples of how you actually do that online so I got stuck into the topic where there are examples (dynamically requiring collections' modules) and tried to repurpose that for something close to what I originally wanted.

Comment: If you just install your code as a package, it will be accessible as the same way as code in collects, so you shouldn’t need to fiddle around with that. That said, if you really just want to run some files, you can *also* just use `require` or `dynamic-require` with a relative path, so long as you provide a string, like `(dynamic-require "path/to/my-file.rkt" 'my-function)`, so you won’t need to bother installing anything at all.

Comment: Thanks for that, that's useful. However, I still think I need to work out how to solve my original question. It seems like _a lot_ of effort to include Racket as a scripting language in projects. I've not even began to think about how I'll expose instances of natively-managed lifetimes to the interpreter. I'd need to somehow mix FFI w/ runtime. I guess I can get away with doing `(require (file "path/file.rkt"))`, but that doesn't seem to require all provided symbols, do you know how I could go about that?

Comment: `(require "path/file.rkt")` will require all provided symbols. (The explicit use of `file` is equivalent, but it is not necessary.) That said, I’ve never embedded Racket in anything, only used it as a standalone language, and I’m not sure exactly what you’re looking to do.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Must be tiredness getting the better of me. I've been wanting to implement Racket a scripting language for native applications (~~because Boost.Python makes it too easy~~). So, for example, I'd have Racket functions that resolve to native functions from a dispatch table and some form of interop layer for transposing types properly etc. I'm not 100% sure of how to do it without implementing an entire interpreter VM from scratch, if I'm honest. I'm still gonna look into it though. Thanks for your help. I'll probably look into Emacs' implementation for a vague idea.

Comment: You would probably be better served by asking [the Racket mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/racket-users) about this rather than Stack Overflow. The mailing list is friendly and generally quite responsive, and the people best equipped to answer questions about embedding Racket will be there, not here. It’s also a better format than SO for the sort of question-and-answer dialogue you probably want to have, since SO is generally most helpful if you already have a specific, targeted question in mind already.